# Transcendence of Euler series

Tags: generating-functions, transcendental-number-theory, transcendence

Is the Euler series $\sum_{n\ge0}n!X^n\in\mathbb C[[X]]$ transcendental over $\mathbb C(X)$?

Comment: Does not any algebraic power series has a positive radius of convergence? It looks that the bound $C^n/n^D$ for the coefficients should be provable by induction, looking at the relation for the new coefficient $a_n$.

Comment: @FedorPetrov Indeed, this is, e.g., proposition 2 in [these notes](https://www.mathi.uni-heidelberg.de/~roquette/KONVPOTREIHEN.pdf) (Peter Roquette, “On convergent power series”, 1996-07-16).

Comment: All series with zero radius of convergence are transcendental over $C(X)$.

Comment: Wahoo. Thanks for these very accurate answers. Roquette's paper is very impressive.